# What does "type" mean and is there is a special use for a question mark in ECMA 6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-native, flowtype

In React Native Example Code, you'll find [at some files](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/MapViewExample.js#L36) the `type` statement, which encapsulates 4 properties (I'd like to guess), where the last two ones are suffixed with question marks.

```
type MapRegion = {
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number,
  latitudeDelta?: number,
               ^============   What are these...
  longitudeDelta?: number,
};              ^===========...question marks for?
```

#### What does all this mean? In specification of ECMAScript 6 I can't find anything regarding "type".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is [flow](http://flowtype.org/), a transpiler language that adds static typing to JavaScript.

```
type MapRegion = {
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number,
  // This property is nullable
  latitudeDelta?: number,
  // This property is nullable
  longitudeDelta?: number,
}; 

// The following does not cause a compilation error

/* @flow */
var a:MapRegion = {
  latitude: 1,
  longitude: 3 
};
```

Comment: Do TypeScript scripts have `.js` as file extension?

Comment: @idmean, not yet. The default extension is .ts, however there is an item to allow for .js files to be transpiled in one of the future versions.

Comment: It's flow, not TypeScript.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, fixed it

Answer (score 5):

Facebook is actually using their version of statically typed transpiled JavaScript called 'Flow'. That is what you are seeing here. It is somewhat similar to TypeScript so they can easily be mistaken for each other.

http://flowtype.org/